# Dask + PostgreSQL read_sql_table: incorrect data type index_col

Tags: python, postgresql, dask

I'm trying to run a mean() function on a column in a very large PostgreSQL table. Since I can't load the column in memory I have opted for parallelism and partitioning with Dask distributed.

System config:

```
12 cores / 24 threads
64 GB RAM
SSD
```

I have tried (1) to maximize thread-count (24) with 1 process and (2) I've tried to maximize the process count (24) with 1 thread each.

The problem is that in either case the from-delayed task takes >= 24 seconds. This task mostly consists of sqlalchemy components to setup SQL connection.

The long execution time of the from-delayed tasks appears to be related to the sql queries: my index column is of data type bigint, but Dask produces where conditions based on float (1000.01). This is a huge cost in the entire operation. Even though the Dask dataframe indicates dtype int64, the data itself is actually float.

read_sql_table:

```
data = dd.read_sql_table("<table>",'postgresql+psycopg2://<user>:<pw>@<ip>:<port>/<db>',index_col='<int_col>',bytes_per_chunk=1e6 - 1e9)
```

I expect:

```
select * from <table> where <int_col> >= int and <int_col> < int
```

but Dask does this:

```
select * from <table> where <int_col> >= float and <int_col> < float
```

Why doesn't Dask apply the correct index data type in the SQL query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/dask/dask/blob/master/dask/dataframe/io/sql.py

Solution, starting line 186 in sql.py:

```
parts = []
lowers, uppers = divisions[:-1], divisions[1:]
for i, (lower, upper) in enumerate(zip(lowers, uppers)):
    if dtype.kind == "i":
        upper = int(np.ceil(upper))
        lower = int(np.ceil(lower))
    cond = index <= upper if i == len(lowers) - 1 else index < upper
    q = sql.select(columns).where(sql.and_(index >= lower, cond)).select_from(table)
    parts.append(delayed(_read_sql_chunk)(q, uri, meta, **kwargs))
```